# How to call instance method in predefined class from another class in android

Tags: java, android

I have two classes, shown below:

TestActivity.java

```
public class TextActivity extends Activity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedinsstate) {
    super.onCreate(savedinsstate);
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,MYMapActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    MYMapActivity.ma.displayGoogleMaps();
  }
}
```

MYMapActivity.java

```
public class MYMapActivity extends MapActivity {
  public static MYMapActivity ma;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedinsstate) {
    super.onCreate(savedinsstate);
    ma=this;
  }

  public void displayGoogleMaps(){
    //some code here.
  }
}
```

From the above when I'm calling MYMapActivity.ma.displayGoogleMaps() I'mm getting NullPointerException. I have debugged the code then finally I found that in place of ma I am getting null. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object of `MYMapActivity` if you want to use it. Static fields need to be initialized, too.

```
public static MYMapActivity ma = new MYMapActivity();
```

or make all methods static. If you don't need object from the class. Then you can call `MYMapActivity.displacGoogleMaps()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "ma= this;" as a static variable outside that activity because "this" instance will be destroyed, that's why you get the NullPointerException.

In order to use displayGoogleMaps() , you have to add a static identifier to the method and call it through your class : "MYMapActivity.displacGoogleMaps();"